# Printing data as an array in Python

Tags: python

```
for i in range(7):
    data4 = ( data3['CO2'][i+1] - data3['CO2'][i] )
    
    if data4 < Hdata and data4 >Ldata :
        print(data4)
```

That gives me a lot of answers:

```
0.39999999999997726
2.699999999999932
6.400000000000091
5.0
6.0
```

I would rather display this in an array. I know I can manually input this numbers into an array. However, is it possible to display my answers to the above formula in an array automatically, so that if I alter my original variables it can display them in an array also?

Comment: What is `data3`? It looks to be a `dict`?

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the values in for loop, if you print it will also add a newline at the end. Instead, add the values which will be printed later to an array and at the end, print that array. It will show the values as an array.

```
final_result = []
for i in range(7):
    data4 = ( data3['CO2'][i+1] - data3['CO2'][i] )
    
    if data4 < Hdata and data4 >Ldata :
        final_result.append(data4)
print(final_result)
```

Comment: @aneroid First of all ty for clarification about usage of StackOverflow. As he/she said, if you vote the answers that works and accept it as the working answer, others can use this answer if they have the same problem too.

Comment: @aneroid I also was talking to owner of the answer. I @ you to give you credit about your informations. Thanks for your response too.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by an array. There are `numpy` arrays and there are python `list`. You could create a list by replacing those ()'s with [].

```
data4 = [data3['CO2'][i+1] - data3['CO2'][i]]
```

Comment: That's not a terribly useful list, it only has one item in it.  Perhaps you intended to demonstrate a list comprehension?

Comment: Well it depends on what each element of `data3['CO2']` is. It could be a list or an array inside it. It wasn't clear. The loop was over `range(7)`, but only five values were given on the output.